# String is not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I  am having this code:

BrData is an object of a class having the definition for EndDate.
it is

```
public  DateTime EndDate { get; set; }


BrData.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtenddate.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat);
```

But this throwing an exception that String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What is the value of `txtenddate.Text` exactly? Can you please debug your code and tell us? And please write a better title based on your specific problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: @payal please out tags in tags column and keep a vaid question heading.

Comment: Then it must not be a valid value for the format, per the error message..

Comment: This is the value in txtenddate.Text "07-25-2015"

Comment: DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(txtenddate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"07-25-2015"` is not the expected format of ['.. 01/02/2001 for the English (United Kingdom), "en-GB", culture.'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx), where 02 represents February and 01 is the first day of such.

The correct value per the *Great Britain / UK* locale would be, eg. `"25-07-2015"`. That is, dd-MM-YYYY and not the *American* MM-dd-YYYY.

---

This particular exception-case only occurs for invalid month values, such as "25" so it was rather fortunate to be discovered here - or else the dates would simply be parsed incorrectly with transposed months/days.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I get it. The format of the text has to be in dd-mm-yyyy itself.

Comment: mm means minutes of time to be precise use MM